# regex skip prefix if it's there, like country code of phone number

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I need a regex to get phone numbers without country codes, if they're there.  It seems like lookarounds should work for this, but I can't quite get to the final solution.  Here are the subjects:

```
In-country: 0008003428573
Outside: +91 4058 825058
With dots: +91.88.4732.1354
```

The desired matches are:

```
8003428573
4058 825058
88.4732.1354
```

I know I can use `(?!91)` to avoid matching `91` such as

`(?!91)[1-9][-. 0-9]{8,11}[0-9](?![0-9])`

...but then it matches the `1` like `1 4058 825058`.

I also found a complete solution using an if-then condition while testing in Perl:

`(?!91)(?(?=1)(?<!9)|)[1-9][-. 0-9]{8,11}[0-9](?![0-9])`

but then found out it doesn't work with NSRegularExpression in Objective C.

The solution cannot use groups, since I have multiple regexes for different situations that are processed by the same code.  The code can't use group 1 in some cases and group 2 in others..unless there's no way to solve this with regular expressions.  The `91 must not be in the overall match.

Is there a way to do this with a regex in Obj-C?

Answer (score 0):

A solution using groups, please note, that the group with **the result is always in group 1**, since the other groups are non-capturing! A group that starts with `?:` is a non-capturing group.

```
(?:\b0+|\B\+91[. ]?)([1-9]\d+(?:[. ]\d+)*)\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3538d). When you hover the mouse over the match you can see the content of the only group.